# How to make screenshots and screencast from real iPhone via Terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal

Is there any possibility to capture screenshots and screencasts from physical iPhone via MacOS Terminal command?

I've tried command `xcrun io booted screenshot test.png`, but the answer was `No devices are booted`.

As I correctly understood it works only with emulated devices.

On Android devices you can simply write bunch of adb commands like:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/screencast.mp4
adb pull /sdcard/screencast.mp4 *location on Mac*
adb shell rm /sdcard/screencast.mp4
```

It would be great to have an equal on iOS.

Comment: avoid spamming tags as android has no relevance to this question

Comment: Thank you! Already removed it.

I'll keep it in mind for my future questions.